# EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to go through the first chapter code of the book Ang-Book2 (https://www.ng-book.com/2/), and everything is fine, it is gives me the same output as it is in the book, but in the console it is writing:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./ArticleComponent class ArticleComponent - inline template:3:27 caused by: Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined
```

This is the code of the main component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class Article {
  title: string;
  link: string;
  votes: number;

  constructor(title: string, link: string, votes: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.votes = votes;
  }

  domain(): string {
    try {
      const link: string = this.link.split('//')[1];
      return link.split('/')[0];
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  voteUp(): void {
    this.votes += 1;
  }

  voteDown(): void {
    this.votes -= 1;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'reddit-article',
  inputs: ['article'],
  host: {
    class: 'row'
  },
  template: `
    <div class="four wide column center aligned votes">
      <div class="ui statistic">
        <div class="value">
          {{ article.votes }}
        </div>
        <div class="label">
          Points
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="twelve wide column">
      <a class="ui large header" href="{{ article.link }}">
        {{ article.title }}
      </a>
      <div class="meta">({{ article.domain() }})</div>
      <ul class="ui big horizontal list voters">
        <li class="item">
          <a href (click)="voteUp()">
            <i class="arrow up icon"></i>
              upvote
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href (click)="voteDown()">
            <i class="arrow down icon"></i>
            downvote
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ArticleComponent {
  article: Article;

  voteUp(): boolean {
    this.article.voteUp();
    return false;
  }

  voteDown(): boolean {
    this.article.voteDown();
    return false;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'reddit',
  template: `
    <form class="ui large form segment">
      <h3 class="ui header">Add a Link</h3>

      <div class="field">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input name="title" #newtitle>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="link">Link:</label>
        <input name="link" #newlink>
      </div>

      <button (click)="addArticle(newtitle, newlink)"
              class="ui positive right floated button">
        Submit link
      </button>
    </form>

    <div class="ui grid posts">
      <reddit-article
        *ngFor="let article of sortedArticles()"
        [article]="article">
      </reddit-article>
    </div>
  `
})
export class RedditApp {
  articles: Article[];

  constructor() {
    this.articles = [
      new Article('Angular 2', 'http://angular.io', 3),
      new Article('Fullstack', 'http://fullstack.io', 2),
      new Article('Angular Homepage', 'http://angular.io', 1),
    ];
  }

  addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement): boolean {
    console.log(`Adding article title: ${title.value} and link: ${link.value}`);
    this.articles.push(new Article(title.value, link.value, 0));
    title.value = '';
    link.value = '';
    return false;
  }

  sortedArticles(): Article[] {
    return this.articles.sort((a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes - a.votes);
  }

}
```

Comment: Post your template, that's where the error occured.

Comment: The template is in the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the error occured:

```
<div class="value">
    {{ article.votes }}
</div>
```

`article` is undefined at the moment of the template rendering, you can use safe navigation operator (`?`) to "protect" your template:

```
<div class="value">
    {{ article?.votes }}
</div>
```

Comment: excellent, it worked perfectly